# How to have thumbnails in different folders than the original image show up in media library?

Tags: wordpress

We are migrating a database from a custom CMS to WordPress and one of the challenges we are facing is that the previous CMS stored thumbnails in different folders than the original image (folders also include second and if the thumbnail was generated a few seconds later it would be stored differently) and we are mapping those for the WordPress thumbnails (as there are hundreds of thousands and we do not wish to regenerate what already exists).

The issue is that WordPress automatically wants to add the folder structure of the original image to the thumbnails and therefore breaks the URL.

Consider original is:
2018/12/13/06/18/22771810000000_43_240.jpg

We are storing the full path of thumbnail images like below (serialized in postmeta):
2018/12/13/06/19/22771810000000_43_240.jpg

WordPress displays thumbnail like so:
2018/12/13/06/18/2018/12/13/06/19/22771810000000_43_240.jpg

How can we tell WordPress not to add the trailing folder schema from the original image?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266968/is-it-possible-to-reorganize-the-wordpress-uploads-directory

Comment: @GroupOfOceninfo this is not exactly what we are trying to achieve, our main objective is not to have to redo images as there are so many and it will create unnecessary storage. The above also does things based on a logic that items are stored based on the thumbnail name, ours does not do this.

Comment: I think you have to check media settings for that where you can remove 2018/12/13/06/18 so WordPress don't organised stuff accordingly, While you're migrating from different CMS you can upload old images to home directory path i.e. /public_html/2018/12/13/06/19/22771810000000_43_240.jpg and all the future images will go to /wp-content/upload/2019/01/image-01.jpg etc.

Comment: Yeah there is nothing in "media settings" that is the issue.